# hbase database creation

Tags: hbase

I m new to hbase..

There are some errors while creatin table in hbase

```
hbase(main):010:0> create 'test'
11/05/01 12:40:47 DEBUG zookeeper.ZooKeeperWrapper: Read ZNode /hbase/root-region-server got 192.168.1.72:60020
11/05/01 12:40:47 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: Found ROOT at 192.168.1.72:60020
11/05/01 12:40:47 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: Cached location address: 192.168.1.60:60020, regioninfo: REGION => {NAME => '.META.,,1', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => 1028785192, TABLE => {{NAME => '.META.', IS_META => 'true', MEMSTORE_FLUSHSIZE => '16384', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'historian', VERSIONS => '2147483647', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => '604800', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'false'}, {NAME => 'info', VERSIONS => '10', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'false'}]}}
11/05/01 12:40:47 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: locateRegionInMeta attempt 0 of 5 failed; retrying after sleep of 2000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: No server address listed in .META. for region test,,1304233847051
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$TableServers.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$TableServers.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$TableServers.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:298)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:259)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:273)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:112)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:201)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:162)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:293)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:152)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.method__7$RUBY$create(hirb.rb:324)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirbInvokermethod__7$RUBY$createOpt.call(hirb#create)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:243)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:216)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:273)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:112)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:98)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:885)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_0_3$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$eval.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_0_3$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$eval.gen)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:136)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:30)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:101)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:113)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:117)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:30)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallManyArgsNode.interpret(CallManyArgsNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:201)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:162)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:150)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:225)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:147)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:192)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:100)
    at org.jruby.ast.YieldNode.interpret(YieldNode.java:115)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:153)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:119)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:192)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:180)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.YieldNode.interpret(YieldNode.java:113)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:112)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:225)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:147)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:192)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:100)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(RubyKernel.java:1084)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$loop.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$loop.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:263)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:81)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:96)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:192)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:100)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:934)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_1_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$rbCatch.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_1_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$rbCatch.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:283)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:121)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:144)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:135)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:263)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:81)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:125)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:126)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:253)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.block_3$RUBY$__block__(hirb.rb:492)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirbBlockCallback$block_3$RUBY$__block__xx1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:102)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:100)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:934)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_1_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$rbCatch.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_1_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$rbCatch.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:283)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:121)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.method__37$RUBY$start(hirb.rb:491)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirbInvokermethod__37$RUBY$startOpt.call(hirb#start)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:226)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:211)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod$LazyCompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:71)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:253)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.__file__(hirb.rb:497)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(hirb.rb)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:577)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:480)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:354)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:229)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:110)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:94)
11/05/01 12:40:47 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: Removed .META.,,1 for tableName=.META. from cache because of test,,99999999999999
11/05/01 12:40:47 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: Cached location address: 192.168.1.60:60020, regioninfo: REGION => {NAME => '.META.,,1', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => 1028785192, TABLE => {{NAME => '.META.', IS_META => 'true', MEMSTORE_FLUSHSIZE => '16384', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'historian', VERSIONS => '2147483647', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => '604800', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'false'}, {NAME => 'info', VERSIONS => '10', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'false'}]}}
11/05/01 12:40:49 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: locateRegionInMeta attempt 1 of 5 failed; retrying after sleep of 2000
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: No server address listed in .META. for region test,,1304233847051
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$TableServers.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$TableServers.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$TableServers.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:298)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:259)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:273)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:112)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:201)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:162)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:293)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:152)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.method__7$RUBY$create(hirb.rb:324)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirbInvokermethod__7$RUBY$createOpt.call(hirb#create)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:243)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:216)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:273)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:112)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:98)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:885)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_0_3$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$eval.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_0_3$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$eval.gen)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:136)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:30)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:101)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:113)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:117)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:30)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallManyArgsNode.interpret(CallManyArgsNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:201)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:162)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:150)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:225)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:147)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:192)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:100)
    at org.jruby.ast.YieldNode.interpret(YieldNode.java:115)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:153)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:119)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:192)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:180)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.YieldNode.interpret(YieldNode.java:113)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:112)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:225)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpretWithJavaExceptions(RescueNode.java:147)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:192)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:100)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loop(RubyKernel.java:1084)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$loop.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$loop.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:263)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:81)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:96)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:192)
    at org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:100)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:934)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_1_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$rbCatch.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_1_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$rbCatch.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:283)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:121)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:144)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:135)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:263)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:81)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:86)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:125)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:126)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:253)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.block_3$RUBY$__block__(hirb.rb:492)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirbBlockCallback$block_3$RUBY$__block__xx1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:102)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:100)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.rbCatch(RubyKernel.java:934)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$s_method_1_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$rbCatch.call(org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_1_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$rbCatch.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:283)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:121)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.method__37$RUBY$start(hirb.rb:491)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirbInvokermethod__37$RUBY$startOpt.call(hirb#start)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:226)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:211)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod$LazyCompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:71)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:253)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.__file__(hirb.rb:497)
    at usr.local.hadoop.hbase.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(hirb.rb)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:577)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:480)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:354)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:229)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:110)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:94)
11/05/01 12:40:49 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: Removed .META.,,1 for tableName=.META. from cache because of test,,99999999999999
11/05/01 12:40:49 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: Cached location address: 192.168.1.60:60020, regioninfo: REGION => {NAME => '.META.,,1', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => 1028785192, TABLE => {{NAME => '.META.', IS_META => 'true', MEMSTORE_FLUSHSIZE => '16384', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'historian', VERSIONS => '2147483647', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => '604800', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'false'}, {NAME => 'info', VERSIONS => '10', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '8192', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'false'}]}}
11/05/01 12:40:51 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: Cached location address: 192.168.1.72:60020, regioninfo: REGION => {NAME => 'test,,1304233847051', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '', ENCODED => 1526649559, TABLE => {{NAME => 'test', FAMILIES => []}}
0 row(s) in 4.2790 seconds
hbase(main):011:0> list
11/05/01 12:42:25 DEBUG client.HConnectionManager$TableServers: Cache hit for row <> in tableName .META.: location server 192.168.1.60:60020, location region name .META.,,1
test                                                                                                          
1 row(s) in 0.0260 seconds
```

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your full hbase system is not actually up and running.  Check your process list to ensure that you have an HMaster running, a region server running, a zookeeper instance running, a data node, and a name node running.  You also might want to make sure this works all on a single node before you add the complexity of running on an entire cluster.

Answer (score 0):

On your namenode or datanode, run the following command to ensure hbase service rolls (master, regionservers) are up & running:

bash$  jps

This will list the java processes which are all alive. 
Also you can check it up via dashboard if you using cloudera or hortonworks distributed version of hadoop.